# Saving Multiple Select in input

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have model for

- user(id,name)
- section(id,name)
- section_users(id,user_id,section_id)

The admin adds all the  users and sections separately. Once theses are added I want the admin to  selects the section and add all the users in it in section_users

---

I have a select input with multiple set to true. How do i save this data the cakephp way along with validation.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input("section_id"); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("user_id", array('multiple'=>'checkbox')); ?>
```

This generates

```
Array
(
    [section_id] => 1
    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

I know i can loop and convert to this and use saveAll or saveMany but what is the cakephp way/right way to do it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [section_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Umm, how about starting with reading [**the manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) and  the existing questions about saving data with CakePHP, and then check back when you have a specific problem? ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version! Also it wouldn't hurt to know about the associations.

Comment: cakephp version mentioned

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, this is exaplained in the docs, please read them, and in case you don't understand them (which would be understandable as the HABTM section is a little confusing and requires some trial & error), tell us what exactly you are having problems with.

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm**

Based on the examples shown, the format for saving multiple X to Y should be

```
Array
    (
        [Section] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )
        [User] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array(3, 4)
            )
    )
```

The corresponding form could look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Section.id'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User', array('multiple' => 'checkbox')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Add Users'); ?>
```

And the data would be saved via the `Section` model, that way its `modified` column is being updated properly.

```
public function addUsersToSection($id) {
    // ...
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Section->save($this->request->data)) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    } else {
        $options = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Section.' . $this->Section->primaryKey => $id
            )
        );
        $this->request->data = $this->Section->find('first', $options);
    }

    $users = $this->Section->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

Another way would be to restructure the array as shown by Vinay Aggarwal, that works fine, the only difference is that it requires saving through the join model, and consequently it doesn't update the `Section` models `modified` column.

Comment: It wish to do it in habtm table and not user or section table

Comment: And I wish you'd at least try it @aWebDeveloper , because if you would, you'd see that it does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has the `saveMany` function, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html):

```
Model::saveMany(array $data = null, array $options = array())¶
```

Comment: i want for above case

Comment: We're going to need your existing code for the model and controller your using for this.  You have only given the view.

Comment: Do you have a model for the sections table yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is **HABTM** relation, first of all you need have relation setup in `SectionUser` model. Then you can use `saveAll()` method to save all records at once.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 33
        [section_id] => 9
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 33
        [section_id] => 10
    )
)
```

Make sure your data array is in above given format.

```
$this->SectionUser->saveAll($data);
```